# Determining if a function is surjective and injective

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

Consider the function $f\colon\mathbb{Z}\times\{0,1\}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ defined by:
$$
f(n,m)=n+2^m.
$$

For injective:
Let $f(a,b)=f(c,d)$. Therefore, $a+2^b=c+2^d$.

I am unsure how to prove surjectivity and to how to prove the rest of my injective proof.

Comment: What are $f(0,1)$ and $f(1,0)$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Basically $f(n,0)=n+1$ and $f(n,1)=n+2$

Answer (score 0):

Injectivity:

Suppose $a+2^b=c+2^d$ and $b \ne d$. We can assume (symmetry) that $b = 0$ and $d = 1$. Then

$\quad a+1=c+2$

So we have, for example, $f(1,0) = f(0,1) = 2$ and $f$ is not injective.

Surjectivity:

Solve

$\quad a+2^b = n$.

OK,

$\quad f(n-1, 0) = n$

and so $f$ is surjective.

Answer (score 0):

To prove injectivity, we need to show that $f(a,b) = f(c,d)$ only if a=c and b = d.
However, it is not the case as questionned in the comment. Since we can have $f(0,1)$ = $f(1,0)$, where a $\neq$ c and b  $\neq$  d!!! So, $f$ cannot be injective by definition.

Regarding surjectivity, we need to ensure that for every z $\in$ $\mathbb{Z}$, we can  find a couple
$(a,b)$ $\in$ $\mathbb{Z}$ $\times$ $\{$$0,1$$\}$.

So, we need to find a map $\phi$ : $\mathbb{Z}$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{Z}$ $\times$ $\{$$0,1$$\}$.

Hopefully, such map does exist! We need to create a map like this one below.

$$\phi(z)=\begin{cases}
 (\frac{z}{2},0)&\text{if}\, z\text{ is even } \\
 (\frac{(z-1)}{2},1)&\text{if}\, z\text{ is odd}\\
\end{cases}$$

The existence of such map ensure that we can map every element of the domain into a desired couple of the image of the function $f$.
Therefore, this shows that the function $f$ is surjective by definition.